# Push Notification for Chatter Group not Working

Tags: chatter, connect-api

I am using chatter group and implemented the Push Notification using `ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElementBatch(Network.getNetworkId(), chatterPosts)`, but the push notification is not working. Now if i try for single user or loop over the group it work and the notification is getting posted in mobile devices but as soon as i try it for a group the notification feature stops working.

```
ConnectApi.FeedItemInput feedItemInput = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput(); 
ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput messageBodyInput = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput(); 
messageBodyInput.messageSegments = new List<ConnectApi.MessageSegmentInput>(); 
for(CollaborationGroup cgG : chGroup)
    { ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput mentionSegmentInput = new ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput();
      mentionSegmentInput.id = cgG.Id; 
      messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(mentionSegmentInput);
    } 
 ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textSegmentInput = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput(); 
 textSegmentInput.text = 'please check'; messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(textSegmentInput); 
 feedItemInput.body = messageBodyInput; 
 feedItemInput.feedElementType = ConnectApi.FeedElementType.FeedItem; 
 feedItemInput.subjectId = newVisit.id; 
 ConnectApi.BatchInput batchInput = new ConnectApi.BatchInput(feedItemInput); 
 chatterPosts.add(batchInput); 
 ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElementBatch(Network.getNetworkId(), chatterPosts);
```

Note : I made all necessary changes in salesforce1 Setting to enable the Push notification.

Comment: Can you share your code snippet specifically how you are accessing the group and linking the postFeedElementBatch to the group?

Comment: The Code is given below:

Comment: Where did you add it? I don't see anything

Comment: ConnectApi.FeedItemInput feedItemInput = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();
ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput messageBodyInput = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();
messageBodyInput.messageSegments = new List<ConnectApi.MessageSegmentInput>();
for(CollaborationGroup cgG : chGroup){
     ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput mentionSegmentInput = new ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput();mentionSegmentInput.id = cgG.Id;

Comment: messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(mentionSegmentInput);}
ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textSegmentInput = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();
textSegmentInput.text = 'please check';
messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(textSegmentInput);
feedItemInput.body = messageBodyInput;
feedItemInput.feedElementType = ConnectApi.FeedElementType.FeedItem;
feedItemInput.subjectId = newVisit.id;
ConnectApi.BatchInput batchInput = new ConnectApi.BatchInput(feedItemInput);
chatterPosts.add(batchInput);
ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElementBatch(Network.getNetworkId(), chatterPosts);

Comment: Can you confirm the notifications work if you send a message to an individual Chatter user or one group but it does not work if you try to send it to multiple groups?

Comment: The Notification is working for single/multiple users but its not working for single/multiple groups.